Create Calendar in Web app with SpreadSheet's values
I would like to create calendar in my web app with values of specific Sheets with fullCalendar library.
I can have result if I add manually values in my JavaScript function. But I don't know what can make the link with Sheet's values.
Can you help me please ?
Code.gs :
  const classeur = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const fBDD = classeur.getSheetByName("BDD");

  function doGet() {
    return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("Index").evaluate().setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
  }

  function include(filename){
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename).getContent();
  }

Index.html :
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <?!= include('JavaScript'); ?>
    <?!= include('CSS'); ?>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='calendar'></div>
  </body>
  <script>
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",loadCalendar);
  </script>
</html>

JavaScript.html :
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@6.1.15/index.global.min.js'></script>

<script>
  function loadView(options){
    var id = typeof options.id === "undefined" ? "app" : options.id;
    var cb = typeof options.callback === "undefined" ? function(){} : options.callback;
  }
  function loadCalendar(){
    loadView({func: "loadSearchView", callback: showCalendar()});
  }

  function showCalendar() {
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
      initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
      initialDate: new Date(),
      headerToolbar: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
      },
      events: [
        {
          title: 'Event 1',
          start: '2024-11-02T09:00:00',
          end: '2024-11-02T13:00:00'
        },
        {
          title: 'Event 2',
          start: '2024-11-09T08:45:00',
          end: '2024-11-09T12:45:00'
        },
        {
          title: 'Event 3',
          start: '2024-11-09T10:00:00',
          end: '2024-11-09T12:00:00'
        },
        {
          title: 'Event 4',
          start: '2024-11-11T13:45:00',
          end: '2024-11-12T15:00:00'
        }
      ]
    });
    calendar.render();
  }
</script>


See Range.getValues(), Apps Script at Stack Overflow and Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question.

Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your expected result, how about the following modification?
Google Apps Script: Code.gs
Please add the following function.
function getValues() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName("BDD");
  const timeZone = Session.getScriptTimeZone(); // or ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone()
  const ar = sheet.getRange("A2:C" + sheet.getLastRow()).getValues().map(([a, b, c]) => ({ title: a, start: Utilities.formatDate(b, timeZone, "yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ss"), end: Utilities.formatDate(c, timeZone, "yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ss") }));
  return ar;
}

Javascript: JavaScript.html
Please modify the function showCalendar as follows.
function showCalendar() {
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(events => {
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
      initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
      initialDate: new Date(),
      headerToolbar: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
      },
      events
    });
    calendar.render();
  }).getValues();
}


In this modification, when the calendar is loaded, the values are retrieved from the Spreadsheet and the retrieved values are converted to the event data for the calendar, and the event data is sent to Javascript. And, the event data is used with the calendar.
In order to send the event data from Google Apps Script to Javascript, google.script.run is used.

Another approach:
As another approach, how about putting the event data using the HTML template? In this case, the modified script is as follows. The following result is the same as the above modification.
Google Apps Script: Code.gs
Please modify the function doGet as follows.
function doGet() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName("BDD");
  const timeZone = Session.getScriptTimeZone(); // or ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone()
  const events = sheet.getRange("A2:C" + sheet.getLastRow()).getValues().map(([a, b, c]) => ({ title: a, start: Utilities.formatDate(b, timeZone, "yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ss"), end: Utilities.formatDate(c, timeZone, "yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ss") }));

  const html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("Index").evaluate().asTemplate();
  html.events = JSON.stringify(events);
  return html.evaluate().setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
}

Javascript: JavaScript.html
Please modify the function showCalendar as follows.
function showCalendar() {
  var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
  var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
    initialDate: new Date(),
    headerToolbar: {
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
    },
    events: <?!= events ?>
    });
  calendar.render();
}

Note:

In this modification, it supposes that the columns of the sheet "BDD" are "Event", "Start Time", and "End Time". Please be careful about this. When you change the Spreadsheet, please modify the function getValues.

References:

map()
Class google.script.run


It's exactly what I needed. Than you so much Tanaike !

@GowlDesign About It's exactly what I needed. Than you so much Tanaike !, welcome. Thank you for letting me know. I'm glad your issue was resolved. If your question was solved, please push an accept button. Other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question that can be solved. And I think that your issue and solution will be useful for them. If you don't find the button, feel free to tell me. https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer
